# FlashBuilder 4.5 scroll top while saving mxml file

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, mxml

I have strange problem, when i try to save mxml file - flash builder scrolling to the top of editors page ? why ?

it is the same problem like this

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/forums/forum/899337/topic/4612549

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in FlashBuilder 4.5 when the Project > Build Automatically option was selected.

I turned off the feature which seemed to resolve the issue.

Disabling this option will mean that the application will build when you run it rather than when you save it. Also, if you make a change to resolve a compilation error you will have to manually build (Ctrl + B) the application to see if the error is resolved.